# Check if an error is present with error provider

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, errorprovider

I am using an error provider on my windows form. On submit of the form, I need to check if there is some error present on the form. Can I get if there is a error present in the error provider.

Comment: @gdoron, I'm sure he means when he clicks the OK button on the form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write a `Validate()` method that returns false if it fails validation and execute it from `SaveButton` handler. You **should perform re-validation** of all controls of the form in this method.
Continue `Save` only when `Validate()` returns true.

You could use [ErrorProvider.GetError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.geterror.aspx) to get an error of a **particular control** on your form, but to get all errors on the entire form you would need to iterate over all controls that use that particular ErrorProvider instance on your form anyway.